# Conditions ensuring that the outward-pointing unit normal field on the boundary of a manifold has a Lipschitz continuous extension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^\alpha$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, $\nu_{\partial M}$ denote the outward-pointing unit normal field on $\partial M$, $\operatorname P_M(x)$ denote the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb R^d$ onto $T_x\:M$ for $x\in M$ and $\operatorname P_{\partial M}(x)$ denote the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb R^d$ onto $T_x\:\partial M$ for $x\in\partial M$.

Clearly, $$\operatorname P_{\partial M}=\left.\operatorname P_M\right|_{\partial M}-\nu_{\partial M}\otimes\nu_{\partial M}\tag1.$$

Moreover, if $\Omega$ is an open subset of $M$, $\phi$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism of $\Omega$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb H^k:=\mathbb R^{k-1}\times[0,\infty)$ and $(e_1,\ldots,e_k)$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^k$, then $$\sigma_i(x):=T_x(\phi)^{-1}e_i\;\;\;\text{for }i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$$ is a basis of $T_x\:M$ for all $x\in\Omega$.  Let $(\tau_1(x),\ldots,\tau_k(x))$ denote the orthonormal basis of $T_x\:M$ obtained from $(\sigma_1(x),\ldots,\sigma_k(x))$  by the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process for $x\in\Omega$. Clearly, $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k$ and hence $\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_k$ are $C^{\alpha-1}$-differentiable. Moreover, $$\left.\operatorname P_M\right|_\Omega=\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_i\otimes\tau_i\tag2.$$

Since $\Omega$ was arbitrary, $\operatorname P_M$ and hence $\operatorname P_{\partial M}$ are $C^{\alpha-1}$-differentiable.

> Assume $\partial M$ is closed. If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$ with $\partial M\subseteq O$, then it follows from Lemma 2.26 of [Jack Lee](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6751/jack-lee)'s [*Introduction to smooth manifolds*](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781441999818) that there is a $\overline{\operatorname P}_{\partial M}\in C^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d))$ with $$\operatorname{supp}\overline{\operatorname P}_{\partial M}\subseteq O\tag3$$ and $$\left.\overline{\operatorname P}_{\partial M}\right|_{\partial M}=\operatorname P_{\partial M}\tag4.$$ I wonder whether it can be shown that $\overline{\operatorname P}_{\partial M}$ can be chosen to be Lipschitz continuous.
>
> Note that this is clearly the case if $\alpha\ge2$ and $\partial M$ is bounded, since then $U$ can be chosen to be be bounded and hence, by $(3)$, $\overline{\operatorname P}_{\partial M}\in C^1_c(\mathbb R^d,\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d))\subseteq C^{0,\:1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d))$.
>
> In the same manner, I'd be interested under which assumption $\nu_{\partial M}$ has a Lipschitz continuous $C^{\alpha-1}$-extension to $\mathbb R^d$.